Итератор в цикле отличается от итератора списка
Пытаясь реализовать метод reduce() из модуля functools, я столкнулся с непониманием работы итератора. При использовании метода iter(), мы получаем итератор списка seq и присваиваем к переменной seqIter, после чего методом next() передаем первый элемент списка в переменную value.
Однако при выполнении цикла for, у нас используется итератор x для итерируемого объекта seqIter, что в свою очередь является итератором списка. Вопрос, чему будет равен x на каждом кругу цикла?
На данном куске кода, мы видим реализацию метода reduce для сложения чисел в списке:
def reduce(func, seq):
    seqIter = iter(seq)
    value = next(seqIter)
    for x in seqIter:
        value = func(value, x)
    return value

list = [1,2,3]
print("Sum seq is:", reduce(lambda x,y: x+y, list))

Результат:
python .\reduceImplemention.py
Sum seq is: 6

В попытках сократить код, получилось следующее:
def reduce(func, seq):
    value = next(iter(seq))
    for x in iter(seq):
        value = func(value, x)
    return value

list = [1,2,3]
print("Sum seq is:", reduce(lambda x,y: x+y, list))

Исходя из правила, что интерпретация строки начинается со скобок(как в математике), должно было выполниться выражение iter(seq), после чего остальная строка. Также методом iter() передаем в цикл for итератор списка seq. Однако результат становится равным:
python .\reduceImplemention.py
Sum seq is: 7

Возможно, что дело в цикле for, поэтому создаем переменную seqIter и присваиваем iter(seq) и также меняем в цикле на for x in seqIter. Результат остался тем же:
python .\reduceImplemention.py
Sum seq is: 7

Следовательно вопрос: Почему метод next не применился в самом начале блока кода метода reduce. Или дело в условии цикла?

Потому что вы создали два разных итератора

Итератор это указатель, получается, что я создал два разных итератора, которые хранят в себе разные адреса в памяти на один и тот же список?

Суть примерно такая, ага

вы дважды используете итератор iter(seq) без сохранения состояния итератора. Когда вы пишете for x in iter(seq), вы фактически создаете новый итератор для последовательности seq в каждый момент цикла, что приводит к тому, что на первом шаге цикла вы не учитываете элемент, который вы уже забрали с помощью next(seqIter) в первой версии кода. Таким образом, на первом шаге цикла вы начинаете с первого элемента списка, а затем в цикле пропускаете его и начинаете с второго.
чтобы исправить это, нужно использовать один и тот же итератор в обоих случаях. по типу:
def reduce(func, seq):
    seqIter = iter(seq)
    value = next(seqIter)
    for x in seqIter:
        value = func(value, x)
    return value

list = [1, 2, 3]
print("Sum seq is:", reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, list))  # Результат: 6

тут seqIter создается один раз, и его состояние сохраняется в ходе выполнения цикла

«в каждый момент цикла» — то ли формулировка корявая, то ли чушь написана, итератор для цикла создаётся ровно один раз для всех «моментов» цикла

В качестве чисто академического интереса задался вопросом, можно ли реализовать аналог reduce без итераторов. Решение на итераторах прекрасно, сомнений нет.
Решил реализовать на генераторах.
Вариант reduce1 компактное, но имеет недостаток: в "*_" хранится кортеж ранее вычисленных значений func. Памятуя о 28+ байт, решение сгодится для маленьких списков. Хотя наверняка существуют ситуации, когда подобный побочный эффект будет полезен.
Вариант reduce2 избавлено от недостатка первого варианта, но для прогона генератора требуется холостой цикл for.
Вариант reduce3 требует подключения модуля collections и создание класса deque. Можно создать свой маленький класс, но это загромождает код. Этот вариант что то среднее между предыдущими. По памяти создается "лишний" экземпляр класса deque, но зато deque автоматически потребляет генератор. В deque храниться только одно значение - последний результат вызова func.
P.S. Если кто-то знает более "приличный" вариант получения последнего элемента генератора, буду благодарен.
from collections import deque

def reduce1(func, seq):
    value = None
    try:
        *_, result = (value := x if value is None else func(value, x) for x in seq)
    except Exception as exc:
        raise TypeError("reduce() of empty iterable with no initial value") from exc
    return result

def reduce2(func, seq):
    value = None
    g = (value := x if value is None else func(value, x) for x in seq)
    for _ in g: pass
    if value:
        return value
    else:
        raise TypeError("reduce() of empty iterable with no initial value") from None

def reduce3(func, seq):
    value = None
    g = (value := x if value is None else func(value, x) for x in seq)
    result = deque(g,1)
    try:
        return result.pop()
    except Exception as exc:
        raise TypeError("reduce() of empty iterable with no initial value") from exc

Старый вариант имеет ряд недостатков, отмеченных в комментариях:
def reduce(func, seq):
    value = 0
    for x in iter(seq):
        value = func(value, x)
    return value


Это создаёт дополнительный нежелательный вызов func

вызов func изначально был)

Нет, в самом первом варианте от автора вопроса лишних вызовов не было

Не хотелось бы использовать объявление переменной, т.к после присваивания значения 0, у нас код будет потреблять на 28+- байтов памяти

@Radiance питон сразу после запуска потребляет 17068032 байт памяти, нашли блин на чём экономить)

Мда, 28+ байтов памяти для Python - это сильно. С такими жесткими ограничениями - это С.

А iter() и next() разве не вызовы функций? Неужели это дешевле дополнительного однократного вызова func()?

@VladimirBogdanov речь не про стоимость, а про нужность — func не будет ожидать, что её вызовут лишний раз и при этом подсунут какой-то непонятно откуда взявшийся ноль. Настоящая functools.reduce из стандартной библиотеки питона так себя не ведёт

Тогда зачем велосипед изобретать? Чем не устраивает библиотечный reduce? Для справки код из библиотеки:def reduce(function, sequence, initial=_initial_missing):
it = iter(sequence)
if initial is _initial_missing:
    try:
        value = next(it)
    except StopIteration:
        raise TypeError(
            "reduce() of empty iterable with no initial value") from None
else:
    value = initial

for element in it:
    value = function(value, element)

return value


@VladimirBogdanov очевидно в образовательных целях)

...ну или чтобы 28 байт памяти сэкономить, потратив пару килобайт на создание новой функции )))

@VladimirBogdanov В начале своего вопроса, я сообщил о методе reduce из библиотеки:)

А теперь представьте, что в качестве func вам передали умножение: lambda x,y: x*y, какой будет результат с таким подходом? Невозможно предусмотреть нейтральное начальное значение для reduce на все случаи жизни.

Ой, теперь все старые комменты стали невалидны

Наоборот, старые комменты заставили меня задуматься. Вот что делает животворящая критика.

В таких случаях лучше давать новый ответ, а не переделывать тотально старый :/

Вернул старый вариант.
